# Get JSONP Data via Yahoo API YQL- Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp, yql, yahoo-api

I have an api from one of my vendors that returns JSON data the api is as below:-
http://shipdesk.in/mobile/mobile_quick.php?country=IN&to_country=IN&pin=560001&weight=2.5&unit=KG&need_cod=No&to_pin=700001

Now this API does not have JSONP coding so I cannot attach `&callback=processJSON`to this.

I've read that Yahoo Api can convert this from JSON to JSONP which I can use in my website but I have not succeeded the same.

Also my website has several restrictions so I cannot write php code for this. It has to be done in Javascript.

The JSONP code (with another example) that works is as below:-

```
<span id='test'>nothing</span>

<script>
    function processJSON(json) {
        // Do something with the JSON response

        result = JSON.stringify(json);

        //alert(result);
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = result;

    };
</script>

<script src='http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=monkey&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=processJSON'></script>
```

Any ideas, links, tutorials and code snippets will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you expected. 
Using the Yahoo API to convert normal JSON to JSONP type ([yahoo link](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/response.html)) :

```
<span id='test'>nothing</span>

<script>
/* function processJSON (json) {
  // Do something with the JSON response

result=JSON.stringify(json);

//alert(result);
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = result;

};
*/ 
</script>

<script>
var yql_url = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql';
var url = 'http://shipdesk.in/mobile/mobile_quick.php?country=IN&to_country=IN&pin=560001&weight=2.5&unit=KG&need_cod=No&to_pin=700001';

$.ajax({
  'url': yql_url,
  'data': {
    'q': 'SELECT * FROM json WHERE url="'+url+'"',
    'format': 'json',
    'jsonCompat': 'new',
  },
  'dataType': 'jsonp',
  'success': function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response);
  },
  'error': function(error) {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "error";
  }
});
</script>
```

New script tag has ajax call to yahoo api using our url. 
But you should trust Yahoo with your API response data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a billion, it works like a charm. And ya I trust yahoo for my API :P

Comment: Funny thing is that it's working with a to_pin=700001 but not with a to_pin=400001. Is there some kind of limit as to how many APIs can be accessed.